# retrofit 2.3.0 how to handle nested json?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am kinda of new to retrofit and i am not sure how to handle a nested json structure like this. if any one can help how to parse this type of structure . i would really i appreciate it . i have been stuck for days

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 20,
"articles": [
{
"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Bradenton.com"
},
"author": "By EILEEN NG  Associated Press",
"title": "Malaysia says search for missing plane to end in June",
"description": "An official says the search for Malaysia Airlines Flight 370 by a U.S. company will likely end in June, as families of passengers marked the fourth anniversary of the plane's disappearance with hope that the world's biggest aviation mystery will be solved.",
"url": "http://www.bradenton.com/news/business/article203286984.html",
"urlToImage": "http://www.mcclatchy-wires.com/incoming/ukogzw/picture203286949/alternates/LANDSCAPE_1140/Malaysia_Missing_Plane_57970.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2018-03-03T09:42:00Z"
}
]
}
```

Comment: seems that the json array is wrong. where is the closing JsonArray "[" u wrote after the key "articles"? and what is "-" doing in the JSON String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert your json to POJO and use that for retrofit 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Create some pojos:

```
class Source {
   String id;
   String name;
}

class Article{
   Source source;
   String author;
   String title;
   String description;
   String url;
   String urlToImage;
   String publishedAt;
}

class GetArticlesResponse{
   String status;
   int totalResults;
   List<Article> articles;
}
```

And then pass GetArticlesResponse to your retrofit call.

```
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Call;
public interface YourInterface {
  @GET("your_end_point")
  Call<Response<GetArticlesResponse>> getArticles();
}
```

or if you're using RX:

```
import retrofit2.Response;
import rx.Observable;

public interface YourInterface {
  @GET("your_end_point")
  Observable<Response<GetArticlesResponse>> getArticles();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many classes you need to make ,just copy and paste your json here [click here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org).

This will help you and make your work easy.

Answer (score 0):

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("totalResults")
@Expose
private Integer totalResults;
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
private List<Article> articles = null;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Integer getTotalResults() {
return totalResults;
}

public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
this.totalResults = totalResults; 
}

public List<Article> getArticles() {
return articles;
}

public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
this.articles = articles;
}

}
```

Article.java

```
public class Article {

 @SerializedName("source")
 @Expose
 private Source source;
 @SerializedName("author")
 @Expose
 private String author;
 @SerializedName("title")
 @Expose
 private String title;
 @SerializedName("description")
 @Expose
 private String description;
 @SerializedName("url")
 @Expose
 private String url;
 @SerializedName("urlToImage")
 @Expose
 private String urlToImage;
 @SerializedName("publishedAt")
 @Expose
 private String publishedAt;

 public Source getSource() {
 return source;
 }

 public void setSource(Source source) {
 this.source = source;
 }

 public String getAuthor() {
 return author;
 }

 public void setAuthor(String author) {
 this.author = author;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
 return title;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
 this.title = title;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
 return description;
 }

 public void setDescription(String description) {
 this.description = description;
 }

 public String getUrl() {
 return url;
 }

 public void setUrl(String url) {
 this.url = url;
 }

 public String getUrlToImage() {
 return urlToImage;
 }

 public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
 this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
 }

 public String getPublishedAt() {
 return publishedAt;
 }

 public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
 this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
 }

 }
```

Source.java

```
public class Source {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Object id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public Object getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Object id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

Retrofit Interface

```
public interface YourInterface {
@GET("whatever api u are using")
Call<MainClass> getData(@Query("whatever key") String/int(whatever name)) //or leave blank
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well when working with retrofit i suggest using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library with it which parses your json to an object type you should have created so first you should create an object representing your object from the response you get so it will be something like this in your case

```
public class Article implements Serializable {
private String author;
private String title;
private String description;
private String url;
private String urlToImage;
private String publishedAt;
private Source source;

public Story() {

}

public Story(String author,
             String title,
             Source source,
             String description,
             String url,
             String urlToImage,
             String publishedAt) {

    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.source = source;
    this.url = url;
    this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
    this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public double getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrlToImage() {
    return urlToImage;
}

public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
    this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
}

public String getPublishedAt() {
    return publishedAt;
}

public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
    this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
}

public Source getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(Source source) {
    this.source = source;
}
}
```

and similarly create your other class which is the Source class containing your Source object

```
public class Source implements Serializable {
   private id id;
   private String name;

   public Source() {

   }

   public Source(int id,
         String name) {

       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
   }

   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
 }
```

now in your retrofit api code you could do something like this

```
 @GET("YOUR_ENDPOINT/")
 Call<JsonObject> getArticles(... put your required fields here example ...@Query("token") String token);
```

and in your activity do something like this

```
List mArticleList = new ArrayList<>();
String mTotalResults = "";
UserApi service  =  ServiceGenerator.createService(UserApi.class);
Call<JsonObject> result = service.getArticles(token);

result.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        if (response.code() == 200) {
           mArticleList = null;
           JsonArray data = response.body().getAsJsonObject("data").getAsJsonArray("articles");
           mArticleList = new Gson().fromJson(data.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Article>>(){}.getType());
           mTotalResults = response.body().getAsJsonObject("data").getAsString("totalResults");
//if you want it as an integer you could do something like 
           int totalResults = Integer.parseInt(mTotalResults);
           //... do what you want with your list
           //...
         }
    }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                //do what you have to do in case of error
            }
        });
    }
```

hope this helps